# Check if number is divisible by three and two

Tags: python, python-3.x

Looks next nested if a little structure redundancy? Any better way for next nested if?

```
# !/usr/bin/python3

num = int(input("enter number"))
if num%2 == 0:
   if num%3 == 0:
      print ("Divisible by 3 and 2")
   else:
      print ("divisible by 2 not divisible by 3")
else:
   if num%3 == 0:
      print ("divisible by 3 not divisible by 2")
   else:
      print  ("not Divisible by 2 not divisible by 3")
```

Comment: Do you need to check one specific number, or are you checking some consecutive numbers in sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking for division by 2 and 3 separately twice, you can make use of the fact that:

$$ 2 * 3 = 6$$

```
num = int(input("enter number"))
if num % 6 == 0:
    print("Divisible by 3 and 2")
elif num % 3 == 0:
    print("divisible by 3 not divisible by 2")
elif num % 2 == 0:
    print("divisible by 2 not divisible by 3")
else:
    print("not Divisible by 2 not divisible by 3")
```

python [pep8 suggests to use 4-whitespace](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id17) nesting as indentation levels.

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

---

If you have more numbers to check divisibility against, keep a set of the numbers for which `num % x == 0`, and print the factors at the end.

Comment: Is it intentional that some of the print statements are indented 6 spaces in instead of 4 spaces?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt my mistake. fixed

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is its worst-case performance, if we consider modulation to be costly. If there are many "divisible by neither 2 nor 3" cases, then there will be many triple-modulations, whereas the approach of putting mod-2 and mod-3 results in boolean variables will only ever have worst-case two modulations.

Comment: @Reinderien I don't think modulo operations are that costly.

Comment: Depends on whether you're running on a microcontroller :) Also, this is a classic interview question. It's entirely possible for the interviewers to add that stipulation.

Comment: I would say modulo operations _are_ (or, rather, can be) pretty darn costly.  But one only needs to perform a single modulo operation. The result of `n % 6` will be `0` iff 6 is a factor `n`; `3` iff 3 is a factor; and either `2` or `4` iff `n` is even.